# How do I fix the problem with this condition?

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop

Basically, learning through the K&R book I got into an entab exercice, and its objective is to change blanks by `\t` correctly when they can be replaced to minimize the use of characters. For example: `"hello   "` can be written as `"hello\t"` considering a 8 blanks equivalent tab stop. My program is changing 8 blanks sequentially by a `\t`, and can also leave normal blanks on their places, however, when I have a situation like this: `"hihi    hihihi  "` that could be written as `"hihi\thihihi\t"`, the final tab don't gets added. That's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define STDTAB  8
#define STDVAL  0

// Functions prototypes
void removechar(char array[], int character, int number);
int my_getline(char array[MAXLINE]);
void entab(char array[]);

int main() {
  char array[MAXLINE];
  int len = STDVAL;
  while ((len = my_getline(array)) != 0) {
    entab(array);
    printf("%s", array);
  }
  
}

void removechar(char array[], int character, int number) {
  int length;
  int out_idx, in_idx;

  
  // Determining array length
  for (length = STDVAL; array[length] != '\0'; ++length) {
    ;
  }
  // Length is increased by one to include the null character
  ++length;


  // Iterate over all array elements
  for (out_idx = STDVAL; out_idx <= length; ++out_idx) {
    if (array[out_idx] == character && number > 0) {
      for (in_idx = out_idx; in_idx <= length; ++in_idx) {
        array[in_idx] = array[in_idx+1];
      }
      // Resize length after removing one character
      --length;

      // Return one index on outer loop to check the previous character before proceeding
      --out_idx;

      --number;
    }
  }
}

int my_getline(char array[MAXLINE]) {
  int input, i;
  for (i = STDVAL; (input = getchar()) != EOF && input != '\n' && i < MAXLINE-2; ++i) {
    array[i] = input;
  }
  if (input == '\n') {
    array[i] = '\n';
    ++i;
  }
  array[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}

void entab(char array[]) {
  int i;
  int length = STDVAL;
  int blankcounter = STDVAL;
  int normalchar = STDVAL;
  char copy[MAXLINE];

  for (i = STDVAL; array[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    ++length;
    if (length > 8) {
      blankcounter = normalchar = STDVAL;
    }

    
    if (array[i] == ' ') {
      ++blankcounter;
    }
    if (array[i] != ' ') {
      ++normalchar;
    }

    // 8 Blanks sequentially, gets replaced by one \t
    if (blankcounter == STDTAB && normalchar == STDVAL) {
      array[i-7] = '\t';
      removechar(array, ' ', blankcounter-1);
      blankcounter = STDVAL;
      normalchar = STDVAL;
    } 
    
    if (normalchar <= 7 && normalchar >= 1 && blankcounter >= 2) {
      array[(i+1)-blankcounter] = '\t';
      removechar(array, ' ', blankcounter+1);
      blankcounter = normalchar = STDVAL;
    }
    
    

  }
}
```

I already tried changing the conditions multiple times, changing the removechar() function, and a lot of other things, however, or it causes more problems, or just don't solve it. The idea here to change blanks for tabs in 2 situations:

1. `"        "` (8 sequential blanks)
2. `"dawd    "` (Characters and sequential blanks without exceeding the tab stop limit)

And leave the blanks as they were in another situations.

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the conditions you're having trouble with? Also, if `my_getline()` is not relevant to the question, we don't need that here. You could just use the built-in `fgets()` to read a line.

Comment: You don't have to write your own loop to get the string length, use the built-in `strlen()`

Comment: @Barmar I'm referring to the if statement located on the bottom of the code, the last one. It should add the `\t` in Strings that have normal characters however don't exceed the tab stop limit.

Comment: @Barmar: What question do you have? The post tells us that for the input “hihi    hihihi  ”, the program produces the output “hihi<tab.hihihi<space><space>”, but the expected output is “hihi<tab.hihihi<tab>”. The code in the post compiles, executes, and produces said output for said input. That is a [mre].

Comment: @Barmar, K&R book doesn't showed strlen() function yet haha

Comment: I think the condition you're looking for is `(normalchar + blankcounter) % 8 == 0` to tell if you're at a multiple of 8.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What do you think is missing that makes it not a [mre]? See my above comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It would be enough to declare a character array containing a string and to apply the function to it.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not using because the book also doesn't introduced fgets() yet

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: That would be nice for a [mre], but it is not an absolute requirement. So if you want it, you need to explicitly tell OP that is what you want. Telling them to provide a [mre] is inadequate to communicate that.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a "tabstop" is to think of a string in terms of "fragments" of a certain length. The key to replacing trailing spaces in each fragment with a single TAB character comes from measuring out each fragment as one scans across the original string.

It's common for beginner's to write too much code employing too many variables as they struggle to solve a problem. There's no need for multiple functions or an overabundance of variables that increase and decrease in value. All too much to keep track of!

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define STDTAB  8

void toTab( char *str ) { // mutable buffer may be "condensed".
    size_t s = 0, d = 0, i; // 's'ource and 'd'estination

    while( str[s] ) { // to the end of the string...
        for( i = 0; i < STDTAB && (str[d++] = str[s]) != '\0'; s++, i++ )
            ; // copy up to 'tablength' chars.

        if( i < STDTAB ) // leave partial trailing fragment alone.
            break;

        // scan backwards and replace trailing copied SP's in this fragment with TAB
        if( str[ d - 1 ] == ' ' ) {
            while( str[ d - 1 ] == ' ' ) d--;
            str[ d++ ] = '\t';
        }
    }
    str[ d ] = '\0'; // terminate the string (condensed or not).
}

int main( void ) {
    char test[][MAXLINE] = {
        "ABCD        EFGH",
        "  ABCD        EFGH",
    };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof test/sizeof test[0]; i++ ) {
        puts( test[i] );
        toTab( test[i] );
        puts( test[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This does not address a trailing newline. My view is that any/all trailing whitespace should be removed (reducing the volume of the text).

The next challenge is to take a string with embedded tabs, and "expand" it out to a string with SP's...

---

**EDIT**
Admitting my mistake...
The above will stray beyond the beginning of the string if the string begins with enough SP's. Below corrects the "reverse scan". The lesson is, always test edge cases.

```
void toTab( char *str ) {
    size_t i = 0, s = 0, d = 0;

    while( str[s] ) {
        i = 0;
        while( i < STDTAB && (str[d] = str[s]) != '\0' )
            s++, i++, d++; // copy up to '8' chars.

        if( i < STDTAB )
            break;

        if( str[ d - 1] == ' ' ) {
            while( i-- && str[ d - 1] == ' ' )
                d--;
            str[d++] = '@';
        }
    }
    str[ d ] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test cases you mention is inconsistent with the requirement:

"hihi    hihihi  " that could be written as "hihi\thihihi\t"

but the input has 4 and 2 spaces not 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STDTAB  8

// write to array[i] and read from array[j]
void entab(char array[]) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; array[j];) {
        if(array[j] == ' ') {
            // read look-ahead array[j+l]
            size_t l = 1;
            for(; array[j+l] && array[j+l] == ' ' && l < STDTAB; l++);
            if(l == STDTAB) {
                array[i++] = '\t';
                j += l;
                continue;
            }
            strncpy(&array[i], &array[j], l);
            i += l;
            j += l;
            continue;
        }
        array[i++] = array[j++];
    }
    array[i] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    struct {
        char *input;
        const char *expected;
    } tests[] = {
        {(char []) {"        "}, "\t"},
        {(char []) {"dawd    "}, "dawd    "},
        {(char []) {"hihi    hihihi  "}, "hihi    hihihi  "}
    };
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; i++) {
        entab(tests[i].input);
        if(strcmp(tests[i].input, tests[i].expected))
            printf("tests: %zu\n"
                "\tgot: \"%s\"\n"
                "\texpected: \"%s\"\n",
                i, tests[i].input, tests[i].expected);
    }
}
```

Consider reworking the interface to return a new string instead of modifying the input in place.